# Power Bi Manage Relationship grayed out

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Can someone help me why in my Power Bi the Manage Relationship is coming Grayed out

I am using the below version

Version: 2.105.1143.0 64-bit (May, 2022)

Comment: You are using Live Connect to Analysis Services or another Power BI dataset, in which case you can't model the data in your report.

Comment: @AndreyNikolov,I have taken data from Sql Server which gets refreshed every day once I click on refresh